# Component Enabler and ActiveLINC (EAE)

Tags: asp.net, unisys, component-enabler

I'm working on a project to upgrade a Classic ASP implementation of ActiveLINC into .Net using the Component Enabler from Unisys, but am having problems when switching between mainframe databases.

The ASP.Net Web Controls (that are created as a result of the Component Enabler running) are easily dropped into ASP.Net and work as expected. But when I try to 'Bye' out of a screen and return to the login page to then connect into a different mainframe database, the first database is still used in the connection process and is where I subsequently get logged into.

This behaviour isn't present in the Classic ASP version of the ActiveLINC site, and I can't imagine that I wouldn't be able to switch databases like this... am I doing something wrong here!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the standard Component Enabler output, each mainframe database is meant to be hosted as an individual website in IIS.

I've created a 'wrapper' website, that in it's basic form, contains a list of links to each individual 'mainframe' website, which allows me to achieve the sort of database switching I think you want. To make this work, I had to make changes to the generic Login.aspx page to accept username/password form values from my 'wrapper' site and then to use these as part of the login process. I also changed the generic Default.aspx to redirect any timeouts, logouts, etc. to my 'wrapper' site, but this will vary depending on your requirements.

Comment: I think that's where I was going wrong - I was trying to make a single website, where I should focus on there being multiple individual sites.  Thanks!